# How to DRY in RequestMapping for RESTful service in spring?

Tags: java, spring

So Ok I've read some tutorials and I can create something like this

```
public class RestService<T, I> extends RestController{

    T get(I id);
    List<T> getAll();
    T create();
    T patch(I id);
    T put(I id);
    T delete(I id);
}
```

Then I can extend in to create some actual service. I would need to annotate get method with RequestMapping("/service/{id}") and use PathVariable.

```
@RequestMapping("/service/{id}")
public T get(@PathVariable id) {
...
}

@RequestMapping("/service/")
public List<T> getAll() {
...
}
```

As you can see I'm repeating "service" over and over again. How can I make something like this.

```
class RestService extends RestController() {
   private String name; // use this name in request mapping somehow.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define a path on a class, and a relative path on its methods. Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public T get(@PathVariable id) {
    ...
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public List<T> getAll() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, OK. How to make this name parameter dynamic? I mean If I would subclass from MyController I want to be able set this name somewhere in code.

Comment: @user1685095 I believe what you ask is not currently possible (I may be wrong). You may use a `PathVariable` that you would test in all the subclasses, but that would still be some repeated code.

Comment: Make it a pathvariable and dont subclass the controller. Or define /{id} on the method and each subclass you put a requestmapping on the class level. They will be joined together at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `@RequestMapping` into class:

```
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class RestService extends RestController() {

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public T get(@PathVariable id) {
    ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once Spring container is initializing application context at startup  it scans all the classes annotated with annotations like `@Service, @Controller` etc.
So, once all the request mappings are initialized and mapped to controller method, it cannot be remapped again. 
To make it more dynamic we can always do something like this :

```
@Controller
public class MyRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/{service}/{id}")
    public T get(@PathVariable service,@PathVariable id) {
    ...
    }
}
```

We can vary the service and id Pathvariable and depending upon the requirement.

I am writing this answer,as i cannot add comment to user1685095 statement.

Comment: Ok, what would happen If a have a service named "foo" and try to access /blabla/. Would it give me 404 as it should?

Comment: Yes, it should give you a 404 unless url pattern '/blabla' or  of something like '/{id}' is mapped in controller.

Comment: well isn't /blabla included in /{service} pattern? Wouldn't spring think that I have a service blabla if I would write as @dotvav suggested but instead of "/service" would write "/{service}" as you suggested?

Comment: Writing it like /service make url mapped to pattern which starts as /service only. Making it to /{service} allows you to make it more dynamic and allows you to change it according to your requirement. You can write it also as : `@Controller   @RequestMapping("/{service}")
public class MyRestController {
@RequestMapping(" /{id}")
    public T get(@PathVariable service,@PathVariable id) {
    ...
    }
}`